# Can I store/record question on SO as private with purpose to publish it later?

Tags: discussion, support

**Update:**

**My logic of creating such feature to benefit the Stackoverflow was having little flow which is corrected by Lix's Answer, which I have accepted.**

Question:

I think "record a question and even maybe an answer as private and then ability publish it at appropriate time", if it is not a current feature, can be a very good feature.

While in the process of storing questions privately, Stackoverflow search engine can play very useful role. SO search engine can suggest solutions for many. Which will in turn save a lot of time of the individual user and individual can gain knowledge faster. Any benefit to an individual user is in aggregate benefit to the entire community.

User Scenario:

I am in a Learning Mode (learning programming, learning Scala). While continuously reading and practicing many questions arise which I may be able to tackle myself or may be I will need help to solve them.

Can I store/record question(s) on Stackoverflow as private?

If I am able to solve it, I will remove it or maybe if it seems useful for the community then I will publish it with answer.

If I am not able to solve it, find appropriate to ask to the Stackoverflow community then I will publish it to get the answer from knowledgeable community member.

Comment: There are so many other services that allow you to store data privately (such as your email).  Why do you think that such a feature would be beinifical to the community?

Comment: @Lix While in the process of storing questions privately, Stackoverflow search engine can play very useful role. SO search engine can suggest solutions for many. Which will in turn save a lot of time of the individual user. Any benefit to an individual user is in aggregate benefit to the entire community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea behind Stack Overflow (and deep below that) is the shared learning experience.  By you learning something out in the open others can spectate, contribute, dispute, discuss the issue at hand and at the end the ultimate goal is a collaborative effort involving all involved and a result of a useful piece of information out there on the world wide web gathering views and educating people weeks, months and even years later.

By keeping your questions to yourself (even if you know that you can solve them), you are preventing the community from doing its job.  Even if you solve this issue by yourself, **and** even post a question answer pair, don't rule out the possibility of someone else coming along and providing a better answer.

You have to keep in your mind the issue of duplicates:

- The first thing you should do is search for existing posts that answer the same question.
- The second thing you do is consider all the possibly duplicate posts that are suggested when constructing a title for your question.

If you are going by your methodology, you are most likely to find the solution within those two steps so there would be no need to "save" the questions anywhere.

If you don't find any other question asking the same thing and you still want to solve it by yourself - go right ahead!  Once you do, and you think it could be beneficial to future visitors then break out the keyboard and start typing!

Answer (score 7):

### Nope

You cannot do this.

The whole idea behind posting a question was that there was some investigation on the askers part as to how to solve the question, and they could not.

Therefore, **asking** a question **before** doing nay research is frowned upon on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to store a question on StackOverflow as private in order to publish it later.

If you have questions you want to ask possibly in the future, maybe use Notepad, etc to keep track of them. Then if you want to ask them at a later date, you can easily recall the actual question.

Keeping track of your questions this way would allow you to search StackOverflow to see if someone else asked it first. If they did, then you could mark it as a favorite so you can easily find it.